# bash completion processing gone bad, how to debug?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

It all started with a simple

```
alias gv='gvim --remote-quiet'
```

and now `gv` <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> gives nothing where it normally should give filenames. Oddly,

```
alias gvi='gvim --remote-quiet'
```

works as expected. I clearly have a workaround, but I'd like to know what is catching my `gv` for special processing. `compopt` is no help as `gv` shares the same settings as `ls` which does filename completion correctly.

```
$compopt gv
compopt +o bashdefault +o default +o dirnames -o filenames +o nospace +o plusdirs gv
$ compopt ls
compopt +o bashdefault +o default +o dirnames -o filenames +o nospace +o plusdirs ls
```

The `complete` command is slightly more helpful but it doesn't tell me why my two characters got singled out for alteration:

```
$ complete -p gv
complete -o filenames -F _filedir_xspec gv
$ complete -p ls
complete -o filenames -F _longopt ls
$ complete -p echo
bash: complete: echo: no completion specification
$ alias gvi='gvim --remote-silent'
$ complete -p gvi
bash: complete: gvi: no completion specification
```

Where did `complete -o filenames -F _filedir_xpec gv` come from?

Comment: +1 for completeness and <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it, finally. It was hiding in `/etc/bash_completions` which - ironically - I overlooked as it didn't appear on my filename completions.

The helpful bash_completions thinks that `gv` means `ghostview` so it will only allow me to complete filenames that it expects ghostview can handle:

```
complete -f -X '!*.@(@(?(e)ps|?(E)PS|pdf|PDF)?' gv ggv kghostview
```

I think that counts as "too damn helpful". Adding

```
alias gv='gvim --remote-silent'
complete -r gv
```

to my `~/.bash_aliases` file was sufficient.

Comment: Compliments! Great troubleshoot!